# How to get Azure App Service Health Check to work with .NET Framework 4.8 Web API

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-4.8, health-check

I have a ASP.NET Web API written in VB.NET using .NET Framework 4.8 deployed on Azure App Service that uses a custom domain. I'm trying to use the App Service Health Check but I'm having issues setting it up.

I have deployed the Web API into a folder called "server". I've updated the web.config file in the site/wwwroot folder to enforce the following rules

- Force HTTPS
- Redirect requests to app service domain to https://subdomain.customdomain.com
- Any requests with https://subdomain.customdomain.com use app in "server" folder

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS">
  <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false"/>
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"/>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)\.customdomain\.com$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Initialization" negate="true"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect requests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />  
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^appservicename\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="appservicename.azurewebsites.net$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://subdomain.customdomain.com/{R:0}" />  
</rule>
<rule name="Server">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="subdomain.customdomain.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="server/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

I have an endpoint at https://subdomain.customdomain.com/api/healthcheck works if I put the URL in the address bar in the browser. When I put the /api/healthcheck in the Health probe path in the app service health check the instances are marked as unhealthy.

How can I get the health check to work with this setup? What request is sent by the health check? Do I need to change the rule for redirect requests to default azure websites domain?

Comment: *What request is sent by the health check?* A simple http GET to the specified url. If an instance doesn't respond with a status code between 200-299 (inclusive) after 10 requests, App Service determines it's unhealth

Comment: I did see that. When I checked Application Insights I could see the request coming in as http://appservicename.azurewebsites.net/api/healthcheck. The response code was 200 but the app service was still being marked as unhealthy.

Comment: could it be you have implemented custom security so it works inside an authenticated browser session but not when called by the web app service?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 200 when you hit the URL from your browser indicates the website itself is set up correctly.  You can check the logs to see what status code is being returned to the health check when it runs from the app service and troubleshoot from there.

[image: Logs blade]

Query the AppServiceHTTPLogs to see what the status code coming back from the healthcheck is:

[image]

The column "ScStatus" is the HTTP code being returned by the call.

[AppServiceHTTPLogs reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/appservicehttplogs)